# Emacs: Tramp doesn't work

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

I tried to open a remote file via Emacs via Tramp.

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
```

I get a message from Emacs

> Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell

Emacs hung and did not respond to any action after that

Emacs was installed on Windows; the remote file was on a Linux machine.

Comment: Which ssh client are you using on your Windows machine?

Comment: If you do make this work, make sure to post your solution.  As a long-time Emacs on Windows user, I've been unable to make tramp work reliably, even following the various wiki instructions out there.

Comment: C-g does help to stop the hanging Emacs.

Answer (score 71):

If the account you're connecting to uses some weird fancy shell prompt, then there is a good chance that this is what makes tramp trip.

Log in as root, then enter

```
PS1="> "
```

(that's a normal, standard shell (ZSH, BASH, younameit) prompt, one that `tramp` will understand)
then switch to the user account, and launch  `emacs -q` (to make sure that your `.emacs` is not causing this mess) and try to `C-x C-f /sudo:root@localhost:/etc/hosts` and see what's what.

You can (not recommended) also customize the regexp that defines what tramp expects :

```
M-x customize-variable RET tramp-terminal-prompt-regexp
```

My approach :

1. Make sure the variable `tramp-terminal-type` is set to "dumb"

`M-x customize-variable RET  tramp-terminal-type`

2. Test that in your .*shrc and serve the correct prompt :

> ```
> case "$TERM" in
> "dumb")
>     PS1="> "
>     ;;
> xterm*|rxvt*|eterm*|screen*)
>     PS1="my fancy multi-line \n prompt > "
>     ;;
> *)
>     PS1="> "
>     ;;
> esac
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This must be the source of many people's problems and they just don't realize it. Fixed my Tramp bug which I thought was a lost cause.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can customize the prompt that tramp expects (M-x customize-variable "tramp-login-prompt-regexp" but my advice would rather be to make your prompt tramp-compatible (https://github.com/xaccrocheur/kituu/blob/master/.bashrc) and not the other way around

Comment: Can I somehow check what prompt TRAMP sees and tries to match against? I'm a bit unsure what shell that is run and what configuration files that are read.

Comment: @Nordlow: Yes, `M-x customize-variable "tramp-terminal-prompt-regexp"`

Comment: I want all this to be automated. Prompt pattern should be detected automatically for the remote host. How do we achieve this?

Comment: We don't. At the remote end, the prompt can be anything, really. The user could have setup a strange 3 lines non-UTF8 oddity. 
I hear what you say, Tramp should be able to parse *anything* and arbitrarily state "this is the remote prompt" but AFAIK he can't.

Comment: This works for me, but the tests using `C-x C-f /sudo:root@localhost:/etc/hosts` did not work and returned a different error about `sudo can only use the local host` (I would have to configure multi-hop or something). If you altered the `PS1` variable, I recommend trying out the "My approach" section directly, and save the sudo configuration for another day.

Comment: If you're still having issues after fixing the .*shrc file, try restarting Emacs. For some reason this was necessary for me - my guess is that tramp reused the connection it had initially opened, which still used the non-dumb prompt.

Comment: Nobody mentioned the blocker I had: in case the shell is not interactive, the ~/.bashrc file returns immediately (by default in Gentoo). The "return" command should be removed.

Comment: I wrote about it some time ago [here](https://www.bounga.org/tips/2017/11/30/fix-emacs-tramp-lag-and-timeout/) because I had a lot of trouble to figure out what was the problem

Answer (score 18):

Your Windows ssh client is the key here, and the 'ssh' Tramp method is almost certainly wrong.

If you're using Cygwin, then you need to use the 'sshx' method, and you probably need to use ssh-agent to handle authentication. Details are here:
[Using tramp with EmacsW32 and cygwin, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050/using-tramp-with-emacsw32-and-cygwin-possible/2698203#2698203)

I imagine the same applies to any stand-alone ssh client which does not require a full Cygwin installation, but *does* use the Cygwin DLLs. (I mention this, because I'm pretty sure I remember seeing such a thing.)

If you're using PuTTY then you want the 'plink' method, as Alex Ott pointed out. If the Wiki doesn't suffice, a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bemacs%5D+tramp+putty+plink) here will probably turn up solutions for configuring that approach.

Other alternatives I can suggest are:

1. Use the Cygwin-native Emacs. That will be slower than NTEmacs, but Tramp seems to work well with the 'ssh' method, and password-prompting works as well.
2. Host a Linux VM on your Windows box, and run Emacs on that. That's a fairly large hoop to jump through, but it's [my preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050/using-tramp-with-emacsw32-and-cygwin-possible/3049375#3049375) of using Tramp when working in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is a defect of tramp.

The real solution is to prevent loading `.bashrc` when `tramp` is used. (because now it is PS1, but it can be PATH, or any other thing that your `.bashrc` will do that will displease `tramp`...).

This can be done by asking ssh to set an environment variable, and testing it in `.bashrc`:

Add this to `~/.emacs`:

`(require 'tramp-sh nil t)
(setf tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options (concat "-o SendEnv TRAMP=yes " tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options))`

and that at the beginning of `~/.bashrc`:

`if [ ! -z ${TRAMP-x} ] ; then
    return
fi`

Another default of `tramp` is that it doesn't have a variable to pass random arguments to the `ssh` command, we have to piggy-back on `tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options`.

Comment: I like the explanation here, but isn't this approach similar to that in the most upvoted answer, except you're sending a custom environmental variable and not loading bash (seems reasonable) whereas that answer has the shell check the TERM environmental variable and load a simple prompt in the case of Tramp (also reasonable)? Just checking my understanding before trying an approach.

Answer (score 3):

Had you checked [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) for solution? `ssh` is in `PATH`? It's also recommended to use `plink` on MS Windows - see section "Inline methods" in Tramp documentation

Comment: Alex: Thanks, but unfortunately the documentation lacks an example there. Here it is: C-x C-f /plink:user@host:/path/to/file

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is your fancy custom prompt in the remote shell, an easy workaround is to add to your `.bashrc` or equivalent:

```sh
if [[ $TERM == "dumb" ]]; then
    export PS1="$ "
fi
```

After you define your `PS1`.

*Note: the credit goes to [ChasingLogic](https://www.reddit.com/user/ChasingLogic/) as this is their suggestion in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/g8m8vl/tramp_another_waiting_for_prompts_from_remote/).*

Comment: Prior art (just for the sake of completeness):
https://blog.karssen.org/2016/03/02/fixing-emacs-tramp-mode-when-using-zsh/

Original Emacs Wiki entry:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#h5o-9

Answer (score 0):

By the way -- if You need `tramp` to `sudo` -- You can actually [sudo without tramp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672294/emacs-edit-root-files-with-no-tramp) using `sudoedit`.

Currently I'm using this bash function:

```
erf () { SUDO_EDITOR="emacsclient -a emacs" sudoedit $@; }
```

Comment: The primary use of Tramp is not to sudo.

Comment: Yep -- I should have made it a comment, not an answer -- but I was young and foolish.

Comment: @Adobe and your name is a software company name. just saying