# Emacs hangs when using tramp with su

Tags: emacs, su, tramp

after reinstalling my system, I discovered that the emacs tramp isn't working..;.
Here is what exactly happens : 
I type in 
    C-x C-f /su:root@localhost: 
Here emacs asks for my password, which I provide. It then hangs, showing the above string in the minibuffer, and then 
    Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell

Here is what is in the 
    *tramp/su root@localhost* :

```
Password: Password: 
su: incorrect password

Process *tramp/su root@localhost* exited abnormally with code 125
```

And here is what's in 
    *debug tramp/su root@localhost*

http://pastebin.com/0CKD1yM3

The last line :

```
17:13:59.988240 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (file-exists-p /su:root@localhost:)
```

seems to say that the hangs happens inside *tramp-file-name-handler* or *file-exists-p /su:root@localhost:*, but i don't really know what to do with that...

My emacs version is  23.4.1

I would be glad if someone knows what might cause this !

**Edit :** it turned out that this was because my prompt was ill configured... My PS1 variable for root contained colors, and the detection of color-able terminals wasn't working

Comment: Make sure you enter the solution as an Answer, and then accept that answer when you are able (you will probably have to wait a day or so).

Comment: Why was this closed as too localized? If I understand it correctly, it will affect any emacs user who uses colors on his root console.

Comment: The answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363532/596361