# emacs tramp how to avoid bash_profile

Tags: emacs, tramp

Every time I'm visiting a file system in remote machine and I execute a command (e.g. `grep`) the emacs buffer with the result of that command also contains my verbose `.bash_profile` output.

How could I disable this behavior? That is, how to make the remote command only load `.bashrc`? (In tramp my remote method is ssh)

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363532/1729094

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to move everything in your .bash_profile that outputs text to the end of the file and put the following before these commands:

```
If [ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]; then
     return
fi
```

That should do it. Reread http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-shell-setup for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the same issue, and was mislead by TRAMP's documentation saying to put the configuration in .bash_profile to "avoid incompatibilities", but it turns out TRAMP's connection is actually affected by .bash_profile