# Emacs: edit root files with no tramp

Tags: linux, emacs, sudo, ubuntu

Here's a way to open root file in a non-root run emacs:

```
 erf () { SUDO_EDITOR="emacsclient -n -a emacs" sudoedit $@; } ;; erf = Emacs Root Foreground
```

It asks a root password, and once You enter it it opens a copy of file in `/tmp`. Example:

```
$ cd /etc/apt
$ erf sources.list
```

opens: `sourcesXXiOSmYN.list`. So I edit the thing, and save it with `C-x C-s` -- but it's not saved:

```
$ sudoedit: sources.list unchanged
```

How do I make it save the thing? (the feature will be very neat)

**Edit**:

```
 erf () { SUDO_EDITOR="emacsclient -a emacs" sudoedit $@; } ;; erf = Emacs Root Foreground
```

sovles it. Save a file and either -- kill the buffer or `C-x #`. It works.

Comment: @thisirs: make it an ansewer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the -n option. FWIW I use,

```
alias E="SUDO_EDITOR=\"emacsclient -c -a emacs\" sudoedit"
```

taken somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use emacs, but what's wrong with

```
export EDITOR=emacs
# or export VISUAL=emacs
sudoedit some-root-file
```

? Put the export line(s) in your .bashrc and you're done.

Comment: I just tried Your solution with `export EDITOR=emacsclient` (one needs `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` in order to open the file in the running emacs). It seem to be working.