# Emacs tramp hangs with "Tramp: found remote shell prompt"

Tags: emacs, tramp

I'm trying, for the first time, to access remote files via tramp from Emacs on Windows. I'm trying to open a remote directory via `C-x C-f /plink:user@host:/`. However, when Emacs gets to "Tramp: found remote shell prompt" in the minibuffer, it hangs. And not only does the minibuffer hang, but all of Emacs hangs, so that I have to kill it via task manager. This unfortunately means that I can't see any debug information for tramp, because it outputs to an Emacs buffer. How can I go about debugging this?

I'm running Windows 8.1, Emacs 24.3, and plink 0.63.

Comment: For clarification: `C-g` isn't working when it hangs, to abort the command?

Comment: @phils No, `C-g` does not work, nor does any other Emacs shortcut, unfortunately.

Comment: I had exact same issue with Emacs 23.3

Comment: Maybe (probably) this answer can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6956129/1729094

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a very similar situation with tramp ssh, and I can't guess at what your particular problem is, but only that you can get a complete trace by doing:

`(setq tramp-verbose 10)`

Then try the connection again, and after it hangs, `C-g` and check for a buffer:

`*debug tramp/plink USER@IP*`

The level 10 verbosity might be too overwhelming - you can experiment with lesser levels (smaller numbers) to see if it reveals what the problem might be.  Check the docstring for `tramp-verbose`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Useful for emacs folks trying to ssh into a local windows VM