# How can I use ssh with Emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, ssh

I have a Windows developer workstation with Emacs installed and Linux server with source files and SSH server.  How can I open source files on Emacs?

I have tryied:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@host#22:/home/user/file.rb
```

but got unreadable error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need TRAMP for Emacs:

> After the installation of tramp into your Emacs, you will be able to
>   access files on remote machines as though they were local. Access to
>   the remote file system for editing files, version control, and dired
>   are transparently enabled.
>
> The package provides support for ssh connections out of the box, one
>   of the more common uses of the package. This allows relatively secure
>   access to machines, especially if ftp access is disabled.
>
> Under Windows, tramp is integrated with the PuTTY package, using the
>   plink program.

For more info:

http://www.gnu.org/s/tramp/#Overview

PS: Copying and pasting the "unreadable error message" would certainly be useful.

Comment: Tramp has been a standard component of Emacs for a long time, and the original question already utilised Tramp's syntax. The problem was really a matter of which Tramp method to use in conjunction with which ssh client (and associated configuration). See these Q&As for some info on other approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954479/emacs-tramp-doesnt-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050/using-tramp-with-emacsw32-and-cygwin-possible