# Tramp mode in emacs using ssh config

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

I think this is very basic question in using tramp, but it doesn't work for me.
I have my ~/.ssh/config file that points to my amazon ec2 machine

```
Host amazon
   Hostname xxxx.amazonaws.com
   Port yyy
   User me
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ubuntu
   ForwardAgent yes
```

I can easily do ssh amazon from my terminal and I go to amazon ec2 (so my config is right), but in emacs 
I do:

```
C-x C-f /ssh1:amazon:
```

I always get this error
In Aquamacs:

```
Process *tramp/ssh1 amz* exited abnormally with code 255
```

In Emacs:

```
tramp: Opening connection at amz using ssh1...
tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
tramp: Waiting 60s for prompt from remote shell
tramp-process-actions: Login failed
```

I also have other ssh configurations that they ssh to my virtual boxes on my local machine and they have the same problem.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: It's worth to have a look at `man ssh_config`

Answer (score 46):

One thing that's worth trying is using the `sshx` connection method.  That makes tramp try to avoid any non-standard shell configuration on the remote host.

Like this:

```
C-x C-f /sshx:amazon:
```

Comment: Why ssh/sshx are not swapped I'll never understand.

Answer (score 10):

The tramp method `ssh1` forces ssh to be run in ssh v1 protocol mode with the parameter `-1`. ssh v1 has known weaknesses and is insecure. Hence a lot of sites disable the ssh v1 protocol.

You can verify this from the shell with `ssh -1 me@xxxx.amazonaws.com`.

Try other tramp connection methods like `ssh`, `sftp` or `scpx`. You can see all pre-configured connection methods with `C-h v tramp-methods`.

Comment: Thanks you where right amazon doesn't accept ssh -1, but it does accept ssh -2, and I still have the same problem. At least now I'm not doing ssh1 :)

Answer (score 6):

If Moritz Bunkus's answer doesn't solve the issue, then you can configure the verbosity of tramp's output with
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `tramp-verbose` <kbd>RET</kbd>

In particular, level 6 is "sent and received strings" which might help you to determine whether the "Waiting for prompts from remote shell" is because it isn't receiving a prompt pattern that it recognises, or because of some more critical failure.

If it's simply receiving a prompt it doesn't recognise, then you might look at customizing the `tramp-login-prompt-regexp` or `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` variables.

(Of course if your ssh agent is working correctly, then login prompts shouldn't be relevant.)

If you're running Emacs in Windows, then also see these Q&As:

- [Emacs: Tramp doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954479)
- [Using tramp with EmacsW32 and cygwin, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050)

Comment: so looks like the tramp verbose level is 9 on my emacs so it's pretty high. I run it with ssh2 and I get     
    Loading tramp...done
    tramp: Opening connection at ssh2 using nil...
    tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
    tramp: Waiting 60s for prompt from remote shell
    tramp-process-actions: Login failed
hmm any other ideas?

Comment: If the remote prompt cannot be found then I've often had issues with the type of shell run on the other hand. As far as I know tramp always executes commands with the remote shell being `/bin/sh`. Now `/bin/sh` can be a symlink to almost any POSIX-compatible shell, and current Debian/Ubuntu based distros often use `dash` instead of `bash`. Also `zsh` and `bash` are known to make problems if you use fancy prompts.

My advice: 1. If `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash` then try changing that to `bash`. 2. If the `TERM` variable equals `dumb` then do not set a fancy prompt in your RC files.