# Emacs Tramp smartcard config

Tags: ssh, emacs, smartcard, tramp

I use ssh-key based authentication, with the keys being held on a smartcard.  I am migrating to a new machine, where in my previous machine I had Emacs+Tramp set up nicely with the workflow.

However, now I am having issues.  I found a solution, however I am wondering if there is a better way.

## The setup

If I have an `.ssh/config` with the following entry:

```
Host remote
     HostName 1.2.3.4
     User root
```

`remote` has my SSH keys authorised, and if I run `ssh remote` in a normal shell, I am prompted for my smartcard pin, and can SSH with no issues.

However, in Emacs using tramp, I would normally ssh entering the filepath to `ssh:remote:`.  However, in my fresh installation it instead prompts me for a username, and then a password.

## First attempts

Following the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901030/tramp-mode-in-emacs-using-ssh-config/9905951#9905951), I increased the log level of tramp.

It showed me that tramp was running the following command: `exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none remote`.  Running this in a normal shell worked as expected.

I found that running `ssh remote` in eshell had the same problem.

I thought that maybe Emacs didn't have access to my `~/.bashrc` config, where I configure my smartcard details:

```
export GPG_TTY="$(tty)"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

## The solution (is there a better one?)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411121/how-to-make-emacs-use-my-bashrc-file/6412366#6412366) suggested launching Emacs with `bash -c emacs`.

This ended up solving the problem, however I wonder if there is a more robust solution, i.e. one encoded in my `config.el` file, or similar.

Comment: Hard to analyze w/o more details. I recommend to ask on the Tramp ML, `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the problem is caused by inconsistencies between the Emacs and shell environment variables. You can use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), especially if you are using macOS. Or you can just `setenv` manually. Finally, Spacemacs and Doom have their own way of handling it, I see you mention config.el, not sure if you are using Doom, you can refer to them as well.