# Emacs hangs when trying to connect over SSH on Cygwin

Tags: emacs, ssh, cygwin, tramp

I've gone through all available `tramp-methods` or so I think, trying different combos of login and copy programs - none worked. What I'm basically asking is more options then what already is there. The message buffer shows something like this:

```
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending command `ssh   -e none host && exit || exit'
Tramp: Opening connection for host using ssh...done
```

And here it hangs forever.

I can connect to this host using Cygwin `ssh` (it's OpenSSH as far as I can tell). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using NTEmacs rather than Cygwin's Emacs? I never had any luck getting password prompting to work with that combination.

You'll want to use ssh-agent:
[Using tramp with EmacsW32 and cygwin, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050/using-tramp-with-emacsw32-and-cygwin-possible/2698203#2698203)

If it's not that, customize the `tramp-verbose` variable to find out more detail about why it's hanging.

Comment: The thing is - it shouldn't ask for password. the authentication is via the key (which the remote computer already knows). I've managed few times to use Emacs to SSH from Windows to Linux, but every time it was a lot of trial and error. I'll try ssh-agent and see if it makes it any different, but my guess is that it actually is able to authenticate, but for some reason it doesn't get the remote shell / remote shell refuses to cooperate.

Comment: Some more updates: I've increased the log verbosity to maximum and I get exactly the same messages as before. I've started `ssh-agent`, then restarted Emacs, but the symptoms are just what they were before.

Comment: Stupid question: You added your key with `ssh-add` after starting the agent, yes?

Comment: Yup, I did. Actually, I just download the Cygwin build of Emacs and that worked. So, I'm set for now, but I'd still rather use the GUI version for a lot of other reasons. So I'd like to have it being able to connect too.

Comment: FYI you just need to install and run the Cygwin X server to be able to run Cygwin Emacs in GUI mode (or to use Cygwin as a local display for a remote Emacs). It works very well. Cygwin Emacs *is* a bit slower than native NTEmacs, though.

Comment: You're using `sshx` as the tramp method, yes?

Comment: I might consider installing Cygwin X server. I think it's needed for gnuplot too... we'll see, thanks for the info though. And yes, I set it to use `sshx` as a tramp method.

Comment: I'm afraid that covers my experience of the problem, then. Sorry I couldn't help further.