# How do I speed up VMware Player on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I recently set up Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest system running inside Windows 8 using the free VMware player. Everything is working fine, but things are running pretty slow. I use GNU Emacs 23 to write code, but the program really drags. I've tried all the simple fixes I found, like installing VMware Tools, or running it in full screen.

I have 8GB of RAM, and I've assigned 3GB to the virtual machine as well as two cores of my i7 processor, which I think should be more than enough. I'm looking for more solutions to really speed it up, not just small improvements here and there. If anyone answering could use simple English, I would be really grateful, because I don't have too much experience with these things and a simple, step-by-step explanation to help me would be much appreciated.

Comment: Surely the title should say "Windows" in place of "Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 0):

You mention "full screen", so I guess you're running a full desktop version of Ubuntu.

I would guess that the window manager is trying to do some fancy graphical things which either your hardware doesn't support or, more likely, VMWare doesn't integrate with.

So change to a bare-bones window manager in Ubuntu would be suggestion #1.

An even better idea would be to run Ubuntu Server instead of the desktop version, though.

You can install an X server on Windows (Cygwin's has always been reliable for me, although I've never used Windows 8), and that gives you a local display for X applications running in the guest OS.

That's probably less detail than you were after, but hopefully it gets you started.

This answer might help with a couple of the details, although most of the information is not directly relevant: [Using tramp with EmacsW32 and cygwin, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690050/using-tramp-with-emacsw32-and-cygwin-possible/3049375#3049375)

I guess the main points are:

- Set up ssh access on your guest OS
- Install Cygwin on your Windows host with at least X.Org, XTerm, and ssh
- Start the X Server (use `startxwin` if doing it from the command line)
- Open an xterm and ssh to your guest OS, using X forwarding (ssh -X or ssh -Y)
- Run emacs
- Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the latest vmware tools?